# Relationship between closed intervals and rational closed cubes

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> If $\{J_i\}_{i=1}^k\subset\Bbb R^n$ are closed intervals, then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there are finitely many closed cubes $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^\ell\subset\Bbb R^n$ with rational dimensions such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^k J_i\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^\ell C_i$ and $0\le \sum_{i=1}^\ell |C_i|-\sum_{i=1}^k |J_i|<\varepsilon$, where $|C_i|$ is the volume of the interval or cube.

I'm really lost on how to approach this problem. I know for a fact that we can approximate real numbers using rational numbers, but I'm having trouble on using that idea in a rigorous way.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the volume of a cube? Can you imagine a strategy to solve this when there is only one interval?

Comment: Yes, the length times the dimension. So what I tried is first covering the interval with an interval of rational vertices. Then, if we can find congruent rational cubes that cover the interval with rational vertices, we are done?